# Is it possible to retrieve data from Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: php, google-sheets

I wanted to retrieve data from Google Spreadsheet and to show the result on my website, instead of showing everything.

Here is my code:-

```
$logfile = file("<LINK TO MY GOOGLE SPREADSHEET)");
$findme   = 'code200';

foreach($logfile as $line_num => $line) {
$pos = strpos($line, $findme);
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$logfile'";
}
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the manual of the SDK for google drive? https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open#open_files_from_the_drive_ui

Comment: (hmm, that deeplink might be a bit off-track, but I would start looking around in the SDK for an option like this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google has a spreadsheet API for Google Drive: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Here's a PHP library that gives you access to the spreadsheet API: https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client

There may be other libraries out there. Google `"PHP google spreadsheet API"`.

Comment: How do you insert and update rows in the spreadsheet? I have tried to fit what they did with what I am doing (I am doing all of this in a class, and must), but couldn't get it to work. I even tried to add their headers verbatim.

Comment: @MikeWarren: I don't know. I've never used it. My best advice is to read the documentation

Comment: I already did. Again, " I have tried to fit what they did with what I am doing (I am doing all of this in a class, and must), but couldn't get it to work. I even tried to add their headers "

Comment: "They" means the developer of that API.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. I don't even program PHP. Only ever used PHP once about 4 years ago and avoided it ever since. Never tried using google drive API.